# Как перевести django фильтр на русский язык?

Tags: python, django, локализация, фильтры, перевод

Например:
`<div class="bookCard__uploadTime">{{ novel.created_at|timesince|clipto:',' }} назад</div`
отрендерит как *1 day назад*. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как перевести.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю правильно ли сделал

В django.utils.timesince изменил словарь TIME_STRINGS:

```
TIME_STRINGS = {
    'year': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d год', '%(num)d года', 'num'),
    'month': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d месяц', '%(num)d месяца', 'num'),
    'week': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d неделя', '%(num)d недели', 'num'),
    'day': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d день', '%(num)d дня', 'num'),
    'hour': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d час', '%(num)d часа', 'num'),
    'minute': ngettext_lazy('%(num)d минута', '%(num)d минуты', 'num'),
}
```

И создал новый фильтр:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from itertools import chain

register = template.Library()

REPLACE_TIME = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] \
               + list(chain.from_iterable((i, i + 5, i + 6, i + 7, i + 8, i + 9) for i in range(20, 60, 10)))

REPLACE_STRING = {
    "минуты": "минут",
    "часа": "часов",
    "дня": "дней",
    "недели": "недель",
    "месяца": "месяцев",
    "года": "лет",
}

REPLACE_STRING1 = {
    "минуты": "минута",
    "часа": "час",
}


@register.filter
@stringfilter
def fixtimesince(value, delimiter=None):
    if value[0] == '0':
        return 'Только что'

    if value in (None, ''):
        return ''
    if int(value[:2]) in [21, 31, 41, 51]:
        for key, val in REPLACE_STRING1.items():
            value = value.replace(key, val)
    if int(value[:2]) in REPLACE_TIME:
        for key, val in REPLACE_STRING.items():
            value = value.replace(key, val)
    return value + ' назад'


fixtimesince.is_safe = True
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле `settings.py` измени параметр `LANGUAGE_CODE` таким образом:

settings.py

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
```

Comment: Прописано уже, все равно на английском